# Getting nil when string exists

Tags: swift

I pass a long number as string from `FirstVC.swift` to `SecondVC.swift` like:

```
let userId = user.userID // GOT FROM GOOGLE SIGN IN

let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
let navigationController = self.tabBarController?.navigationController
vc.socid = userId!
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

and receive in `SecondVC.swift`:

```
var socid:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(socid) // RETURNS Optional("11365489964475")

    if(socid==nil){
        print("socid is empty")
    }else{
        let i1 = Int(socid!)! + 7778955 //I GET ERROR HERE
    }

}
```

but I get error: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

If `socid` has an optional value, why I can not unwrap the string? **AND** when `socid` equals some other short number everything works.

Comment: can you pass data by delegate

Comment: @QuietIslet anyway, I get this error although `socid` has a value

Comment: does indicate which line you got  error

Comment: @QuietIslet `let i1 = Int(socid!)! + 7778955` here

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your code works but still I think it would be a good practice to avoid the forced unwrapping. Maybe do something like this instead:

```
if let socid = socid, let socidInt = Int(socid) {
  let i1 = socidInt + 7778955
  print(i1)
} else {
  print("Failed to unwrap socid to an integer")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because converting your string to an int is failing:

```
let i1 = Int(socid!)! + 7778955
```

If `Int(bigthing)` fails then it will be nil.

Comment: So how I should convert "big things" to int?

Answer (score 0):

```
let socid = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let mySocid = Int(socid)

    guard let mySocid2 = mySocid else {
        return
    }
    let newValue = mySocid2 + 50

    print("newValue\(newValue)")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let socid = socid, var i1 = Int(socid)
    {
        i1 += 7778955
        print("Te number is \(number)")
    }
}
```